# Creating a breadth first tree C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Can someone point me to a source or pseudo code for creating a breadth first tree.

What I need is a tree like this [image]

S - means on what step the node is initiated
C - means how many childs the node can have

For example I came up with something like this

```
root = new TreeNode(object)
fun(root);

fun(TreeNode node){
 if(node.c==0){
  return;
 }
 for(child in childs){
  node.AddChild(child)
 }
 fun(node.nextchild()) //takes from zero to C
}
```

I know there's breadth first search for traversing graphs and trees but I need to create one in the same manner and have'nt found anything helpful.

Comment: How does your input look like?

Comment: [N-ary Tree](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=n-ary%20tree)?

Comment: Are you looking for a _balanced_ tree? "Breath first" is a term used in _walking_ a tree. Among the .Net collections, the `SortedSet` implements a balanced tree.

Comment: @JuanLopes input is randomly picked unitys `GameObject`. I am generating a random game room (every room is reachable from every other room).

Comment: @DrKoch the tree does not have to be balanced. Childs are picked randomly.

Comment: @crashmstr by the first look n-ary tree looks like a possible solution.